# Why is this USB Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS crashing?

Tags: usb

When I try to install Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS from USB, after a few moments in the installation GUI, the thing crashes and displays the following messages to terminal:

```
[sda] No Caching mode page found
[sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
(1 of 5) A start job is running for Wait until snapd is fully seeded (9s / no limit)
VFS: busy inodes on changed media or resized disk sda
```

What's going wrong? How can it be fixed?

Comment: 1. Did you check the md5usm of the iso file? 2. How did you create the USB pendrive? Which tool did you use? 3. What USB drive is it (brand name and model)?

Answer (score 1):

The `VFS: busy inodes on changed media or resized disk sda` error message suggests that disk sda has defects in the disk, however it is not clear from the error message whether sda is the hard disk that is the installation target or the USB flash drive that you used to install Ubuntu. If sda is the USB flash drive, try making the Ubuntu live USB again with a different USB flash drive. Based on the error message I don't think that reformatting the same USB flash drive and reloading the Ubuntu live media on it would help, although you could reformat it later and use the GSmartControl application from the default Ubuntu repositories to check and repair the USB flash drive.

If sda is the hard disk try using a software solution to fix hard disk errors. Two such tools in Ubuntu are smartmontools and GSmartControl.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to reformat the usb stick and to verify it has a big enough read and write speed to handle the installation.